# Showing plus or minus error in siunitx

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

Using the notation we were taught, 0.0010 plus or minus 0.0001, for example, would be:

> (1.0 +/- 0.1)*10^{-3}s

Is there a way to print this in LaTeX using the `siunitx` package?

Comment: The package siunitx has a [good manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) that gives you this and also further examples of possible applications. Read first the manual before asking. All latex manuals can be found at [www.ctan.org](https://www.ctan.org)

Comment: @strpeter Almost all the questions asked here have an answer that can be found in the manual of a package. Should we stop asking questions?

Answer (score 26):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

%(1.0 +/- 0.1)*10^-3s
\[
\SI[separate-uncertainty = true]{1.0(1)e-3}{\second}
\]

\end{document}
```

See [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) for the various methods of inputting the uncertainty.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution if you want to set this plus-minus notation **document-wide**:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}

\begin{document}
\SI{1.0(1)e-3}{\second}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Putting it as an optional argument when loading the package works as well: `\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}`.